# Simplified ComponentUI

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager

I am developing a UI in swing. I want to add the possibility to choose between two well defined look-and-feels (laf), with the possibility to extend this choice in the future. I do not plan to support any look-and-feel, but I also do not want to be fixed to a given customizable laf (one of the lafs I have to support is the standard windows one).
Most of my UI uses standard swing components, but there is a small number of application specific UI components not making sense to generalize. They are direct subclasses of JComponent. Nevertheless, they have to change their colors and maybe some other small details when changing the laf. The default colors of JComponent are unluckily not suited. I read for the last day articles about UIManager and ComponentUI. Creating an own ComponentUI for each component and look would probably work, but seems way to sophisticated given the lack of generality of my custom components, and the small differences between the lafs I plan.

What I would like is a simpler scheme, which I imagine working roughly like this (I am a beginner with lafs):

- Adding some key/value pairs centrally to the UIManager using UIManager.put, e.g. "MyCustomComponent.background", "MyCustomComponent.foreground1", "MyCustomComponent.foreground2" and so on, all defining colors, fonts, and similar. Effectively simply extending a given laf with some color definitions, but not with ComponentUIs.
- Some function in my custom component is called whenever the laf is changed, and I can get the colors/fonts there.
- If my future I is too lazy, I want to somewhere define default colors. Even better, I would like to steel colors from other JComponents, e.g. the default background from a JTextArea, even though my custom component is not directly related to JTextArea (just happen to always have background colors which would be suited).

How and where would I implement such a scheme? Something like this must somehow work, but I cannot find any tutorial situated between hardcoding a color (myComponent.setBackground), and developing an own ComponentUI hierarchy. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you've basically descirbed is what the Look and Feel API already does.  You best choice is to create UI delegates for your custom components, which defines the properties they should use (for that particular implementation) and even how they should be painted, so each L&F could re-define the rendering process. You should also know, Swing doesn't behave nicely if you change the look and feel during runtime, it's safer to do a complete restart

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid doing. I understand the benefits of the specific delegation model swing has chosen for standard components. But we are talking about application specific components nobody will reuse, and which will never by be included in any default laf. Creating an interface MyComponentUI, an abstract raw implementation, a default implementation, finally 2 implementations for the 2 lafs on top of the component class onlyfor changing the background and foreground color does not feel right.

Comment: But, it's exactly what you're trying to recreate. You could just use `UIManager.get/put`, but it is a little messy and not all look and feels use the same keys, so you'd need supply a branching lookup for both. If the only thing that's significantly different between the looks and feels is the colors and fonts, then you could use a single delegate to support both. It may not "feel" right, but it's the right place for what you want to achieve.

Comment: it does not only not feel right, it feels completely wrong: The component and all its associated interfaces should not be public, I will not guarantee for their interfaces; (ii) the source code gets overly complicated and unnecessarily distributed (iii) doing the refactoring would take at least a week (for all custom components).